# 'Not enough input arguments' error in `ode45` solver in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I wanna use of `ode45` solver in MATLAB like below code:

```
ydot_init=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',[1e-4 1e-4 1e-5]);
[ti,y] = ode45(@(qdot,qddot,t,a,w) func(qdot,qddot,t,a,w),[0 2],ydot_init,options);
```

and function `func` is defined in `func.m` file:

```
function f = func(qdot,qddot,t,a,w)
f = zeros(8,1);
f(1) = 0;
f(2) = qddot(2)*t + qdot(2);
f(3) = 0;
f(4) = a*w*cos(w*t);

f(5) = 0;
f(6) = qddot(2);
f(7) = 0;
f(8)=-a*(w^2)*sin(w*t);
```

Note that variables `qdot`, `qddot`, `t`, `a` and `w` is defined in the code before.

But when i run my code it return this error:

```
Error using @(t,a,w)func(t,a,w)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in odearguments (line 87)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 113)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in Dm (line 116)
[ti,y] = ode45(@(t,a,w) func(t,a,w),[t t+ts],ydot_init',options);
```

Comment: That's not how `ode45` works. [Docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu00_4l-2): "The function `dydt = odefun(t,y)`, for a scalar t and a column vector y, must return a column vector `dydt` ... `odefun` must accept both input arguments, t and y, even if one of the arguments is not used in the function."  Looking at some of the [topics](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ordinary-differential-equations.html) and how to [parametrize functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) may help you.

Comment: In the call to `ode45` odefun should be written as a function with two input arguments `t,y`, so in your case it would look like `@(t,y)func(qdot,qddot,t,y,w)` . I am assuming w is also defined

Comment: Thanks very much +1